# Cmake to autogenerate thrift code

Tags: build, cmake, thrift

So the only decent example I've found for this is http://grokbase.com/t/thrift/user/1162hvgrdn/recommended-way-to-incorporate-thrift-to-the-build-system ,  however it seems to be quite buggy, for example the if statement is missing ${THRIFT_FILE} .

That said I'm getting caught up on execute prcoess command returning: "execute_process given uknown argument -  "STUFF"  where stuff is what looks tobe a proper thrift command.

Any suggestions and what's wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

Better late then never. 
Use [add_custom_command](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command)

```
add_custom_command(
OUTPUT
    ${GEN_FILES_PATH}/DebugProtoTest_types.cpp
    ${GEN_FILES_PATH}/DebugProtoTest_types.h
COMMAND
    $<TARGET_FILE:compiler> --gen cpp:dense ${TEST_PATH}/DebugProtoTest.thrift
DEPENDS
    compiler
WORKING_DIRECTORY
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

I use it to generate test-related stuff for Apache thrift [here](https://github.com/snikulov/thrift.cmake)